# Will tomcat connect to the port it is configured to as soon as it started?

Tags: tomcat, port

I'm a newbie in this area. I want to know if I can listen to port 80 which tomcat is configured with as soon as the tomcat service has started.

No applications have been deployed to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once the Tomcat service has started it will be listening on all address/port combinations for which a connector has been configured.

Exactly when Tomcat binds to those address/port combinations during the start sequence is controlled by the `bindOnInit` configuration parameter of the connector.

Comment: By "when Tomcat binds", did you mean there are events that you can configure during which Tomcat starts listening?